# Error on filtering on data for R Shiny app

Tags: filter, shiny, forecasting

I am trying to crate a Shiny app for price forecasting. price curve categorized based on 3 filed: 1- curve name, 2- peak type and 3- delivery.
I have a question in Server function for my app,  I have following code and ui section is working fine but I think server function filtering on data has some problem, I really apricate if anyone can help me on this.

Data sets"

```
head(data,10)
         date curve_code                       curve peak_code delivery period     peak price
1  0001-10-20          3 ICE NYISO A Monthly Futures         0  2024-05     17 OFF_PEAK 19.05
2  0001-10-20          4 ICE NYISO C Monthly Futures         1  2024-02     14     PEAK 66.90
3  0001-10-20          3 ICE NYISO A Monthly Futures         0  2023-05      5 OFF_PEAK 19.85
4  0001-10-20          3 ICE NYISO A Monthly Futures         1  2023-03      3     PEAK 35.30
5  0001-10-20          3 ICE NYISO A Monthly Futures         0  2023-08      8 OFF_PEAK 39.20
6  0001-10-20          4 ICE NYISO C Monthly Futures         0  2023-11     11 OFF_PEAK 24.30
7  0001-10-20          5 ICE NYISO F Monthly Futures         0  2023-03      3 OFF_PEAK 72.25
8  0001-10-20          3 ICE NYISO A Monthly Futures         1  2023-07      7     PEAK 56.45
9  0001-10-20          6 ICE NYISO G Monthly Futures         1  2024-07     19     PEAK 69.75
10 0001-10-20          5 ICE NYISO F Monthly Futures         0  2023-07      7 OFF_PEAK 53.25
```

and here is my code

```
## app.R ##
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  header <- dashboardHeader(title = " Price Forecasting"),
  
  ## Sidebar content
  sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("price forecasting", tabName = "dashboard1", icon = icon("chart-bar")),
      menuItem(" Log-Return forecasting", tabName = "dashboard2", icon = icon("chart-bar")),
      menuItem("Choose Curve Name", tabName = "controller", icon = icon("th"))
    )
  ),
  ## Body content
  body <- dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      # First Tab Content
      tabItem(tabName = "dashboard1",
              fluidRow(
                box(title = "Forecast Auto-Arima Method", status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE, collapsible = T, plotOutput("plot1", height = 400),
                    verbatimTextOutput("detail1")
                ),
                box(title = "Timeseries Decomposition", status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE, collapsible = T, plotOutput("plot2", height = 400),
                    verbatimTextOutput("detail2")
                ),
              )
      ),
      # Second Tab Content
      tabItem(tabName = "dashboard2",
              fluidRow(
                box(title = "Log-return Forecast Auto-Arima Method", status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE, collapsible = TRUE, plotOutput("plot4", height = 400),
                    verbatimTextOutput("detail3")
                ),
                box(title = "Log-return Timeseries Decomposition", status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE, collapsible = TRUE, plotOutput("plot5", height = 400),
                    verbatimTextOutput("detail4")
                ),
                
              )
      ),
      # Third tab content
      tabItem(tabName = "controller",
              fluidRow(
                box(title = "Curve_name", status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE, collapsible = TRUE,
                    selectInput("reg",label = "Choose Curve name",
                                choices = list('ICE NYISO A Monthly Futures'=1,
                                               'ICE NYISO C Monthly Futures'=2,
                                               'ICE NYISO F Monthly Futures'=3,
                                               'ICE NYISO G Monthly Futures'=4),
                                selected = "ICE NYISO A Monthly Futures")
                ),
                
                box(title = "Peak_type", status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE, collapsible = TRUE,
                    selectInput("reg",label = "Choose Peak Type",
                                choices = list("PEAK"=1,
                                               "OFF_PEAK"=2),
                                selected = "PEAK")
                ),
                box(title = "Delivery", status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE, collapsible = TRUE,
                    selectInput("reg",label = "Choose Delivery Period",
                                choices = list("2023-01"=1,"2023-02"=2,"2023-03"=3, "2023-04"=4,"2023-05"=5, "2023-06"=6,
                                               "2023-07"=7,"2023-08"=8, "2023-09"=9,"2023-10"=10,"2023-11"=11, "2023-12"=12, 
                                               "2024-01"=13,
                                               "2024-02"=14,
                                               "2024-03"=15,
                                               "2024-04"=16,
                                               "2024-05"=17,
                                               "2024-06"=18,
                                               "2024-07"=19,
                                               "2024-08"=20,
                                               "2024-09"=21,
                                               "2024-10"=22,
                                               "2024-11"=23,
                                               "2024-12"=24
                                ),
                                selected = "2024-02")
                )
                
              )
      )
    )
  ),
  #Integrate Dashboard
  dashboardPage(
    header,
    sidebar,
    body
  )
)

#Our Server to get IO from User

#

data=read.csv("ICE data.csv", h=T)
library(dplyr)

#data=dplyr::filter(data,peak_type==c("PEAK" ,"OFF_PEAK"))

data <- data[order(data$last_updated_date,decreasing=F),]

data=data.frame(date=as.Date(data$last_updated_date,  origin = "1900-01-01"),
                curve=data$ICE.Curve.Name, delivery=data$delivery, period=data$period, peak=data$peak_type, price=data$ICE.price)




server <- function(input, output) {
  
  # server logic based on user input
  observeEvent(c(input$Curve_name,input$Peak_type,input$Delivery), {
    
    data <- data %>%
      filter(curve %in% input$Curve_name)
    
    if (input$Delivery == 1) {
      data <- data %>%
        filter(delivery=="2023-01") }
    
    if (input$Delivery == 2) {
      data <- data %>%
        filter(delivery=="2023-02") }
    
    if (input$Delivery == 3) {
      data <- data %>%
        filter(delivery=="2023-03") }
    
    if (input$Delivery == 4) {
      data <- data %>%
        filter(delivery=="2023-04") }
    
    if (input$Delivery == 5) {
      data <- data %>%
        filter(delivery=="2023-05") }
    
    if (input$Delivery == 6) {
      data <- data %>%
        filter(delivery=="2023-06") }
    
    if (input$Delivery == 7) {
      data <- data %>%
        filter(delivery=="2023-07") }
    
    if (input$Delivery == 8) {
      data <- data %>%
        filter(delivery=="2023-08") }
    
    if (input$Delivery == 9) {
      data <- data %>%
        filter(delivery=="2023-09") }
    
    if (input$Delivery == 10) {
      data <- data %>%
        filter(delivery=="2023-10") }
    
    if (input$Delivery == 11) {
      data <- data %>%
        filter(delivery=="2023-11") }
    
    if (input$Delivery == 12) {
      data <- data %>%
        filter(delivery=="2023-12") }
    
    if (input$Delivery == 13) {
      data <- data %>%
        filter(delivery=="2024-01") }
    
    if (input$Delivery == 14) {
      data <- data %>%
        filter(delivery=="2024-02") }
    
    if (input$Delivery == 15) {
      data <- data %>%
        filter(delivery=="2024-03") }
    
    if (input$Delivery == 16) {
      data <- data %>%
        filter(delivery=="2024-04") }
    
    if (input$Delivery == 17) {
      data <- data %>%
        filter(delivery=="2024-05") }
    
    if (input$Delivery == 18) {
      data <- data %>%
        filter(delivery=="2024-06") }
    
    if (input$Delivery == 19) {
      data <- data %>%
        filter(delivery=="2024-07") }
    
    if (input$Delivery == 20) {
      data <- data %>%
        filter(delivery=="2024-08") }
    
    if (input$Delivery == 21) {
      data <- data %>%
        filter(delivery=="2024-09") }
    
    if (input$Delivery == 22) {
      data <- data %>%
        filter(delivery=="2024-10") }
    
    if (input$Delivery == 23) {
      data <- data %>%
        filter(delivery=="2024-11") }
    
    if (input$Delivery == 24) {
      data <- data %>%
        filter(delivery=="2024-12") }
    
    
    if (input$Peak_type == 1) {
      data <- data %>%
        filter(peak=="PEAK") }
    
    if (input$Peak_type == 2) {
      data <- data %>%
        filter(peak=="OFF_PEAK") }
    
    
    #model         
    m1 <- auto.arima(data$price)
    f1 <- forecast(m1, h = 30)
    plot(f1)
    detail1 <- accuracy(f1)
    
    m2 <- auto.arima(data$price)
    f2 <- forecast(m2, h = 20)
    plot(f2)
    detail2 <- accuracy(f2) 
    
    m3 <- auto.arima(diff(log(data$price), lag=1))
    f3 <- forecast(m3, h = 30)
    plot(f3)
    detail3 <- accuracy(f3) 
    
    m4 <- auto.arima(diff(log(data$price), lag=1))
    f4 <- forecast(m4, h = 20)
    plot(f4)
    detail4 <- accuracy(f4) 
    
    
    output$detail1 <- renderText({ detail1[,"MAPE"] })
    output$detail2 <- renderText({ detail2[,"MAPE"] })
    output$detail3 <- renderText({ detail3[,"MAPE"] })
    output$detail4 <- renderText({ detail4[,"MAPE"] })
    
    # Create plot
    
    output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
      plot(f1)
    })
    
    
    output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
      plot(f2)
    })
    
    output$plot3 <- renderPlot({
      plot(f3)
    })
    
    output$plot4 <- renderPlot({
      plot(f4)
    })
    
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I am expecting to have plot for ARIMA forecasting for each curve, delivery and peak type

Comment: Could you reduce this to a MRE? For example, we can't import the data "ICE data.csv" because we don't have it. Read this for some help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks for reply, I just edited my question with `head()` of the data

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't nest all of your `output$.. <-` calls within an `observeEvent`: they are defined once, at which point none of them react to changing data.
2. `input$Delivery` is never defined, that should be `input$reg` (the `box` title does nothing for `input$`-based variables).
3. I suggest a `mydata <- reactive(..)` model that works on filtering the data based on inputs, and then model/forecast/plot that.
4. We can do some significant reduction of code, all 24 of the `if (input$Delivery == 21) {...}` can be simplified into 1 expression. Change your `box(title="Delivery"` to:

   ```r
                   box(title = "Delivery", status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE, collapsible = TRUE,
                       selectInput("reg",label = "Choose Delivery Period",
                                   choices = 
                                       c("2023-01", "2023-02", "2023-03", "2023-04", "2023-05", "2023-06",
                                         "2023-07", "2023-08", "2023-09", "2023-10", "2023-11", "2023-12", 
                                         "2024-01", "2024-02", "2024-03", "2024-04", "2024-05", "2024-06",
                                         "2024-07", "2024-08", "2024-09", "2024-10", "2024-11", "2024-12"),
                                   selected = "2024-02")
                   )
   ```

   Similarly, change the Peak type choices to `choices = c("PEAK", "OFF_PEAK")`. Note that if the `choices=` vector/list is named, then it *shows* the names and *returns* the value; if it is not named, it shows and returns the values.

Try this (untested):

```r
server <- function(input, output) {
  # data <- read.csv(...)

  mydata <- eventReactive(input$reg, {
    req(input$reg)
    data %>%
      filter(delivery == input$reg, peak = input$Peak_type)
  })

  mdl1 <- eventReactive(mydata(), {
    req(mydata())
    mdl <- auto.arima(mydata()$price)
    fcst <- forecast(mdl, h = 30)
    detail <- accuracy(fcst)
    list(mdl = mdl, fcst = fcst, detail = detail)
  })

  mdl2 <- eventReactive(mydata(), {
    req(mydata())
    mdl <- auto.arima(mydata()$price)
    fcst <- forecast(mdl, h = 20)
    detail <- accuracy(fcst)
    list(mdl = mdl, fcst = fcst, detail = detail)
  })

  mdl3 <- eventReactive(mydata(), {
    req(mydata())
    mdl <- auto.arima(diff(log(mydata()$price), lag = 1))
    fcst <- forecast(mdl, h = 30)
    detail <- accuracy(fcst)
    list(mdl = mdl, fcst = fcst, detail = detail)
  })

  mdl4 <- eventReactive(mydata(), {
    req(mydata())
    mdl <- auto.arima(diff(log(mydata()$price), lag = 1))
    fcst <- forecast(mdl, h = 20)
    detail <- accuracy(fcst)
    list(mdl = mdl, fcst = fcst, detail = detail)
  })

  output$detail1 <- renderText({ req(mdl1()); mdl1()$detail[,"MAPE"] })
  output$detail2 <- renderText({ req(mdl2()); mdl2()$detail[,"MAPE"] })
  output$detail3 <- renderText({ req(mdl3()); mdl3()$detail[,"MAPE"] })
  output$detail4 <- renderText({ req(mdl4()); mdl4()$detail[,"MAPE"] })

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({ req(mdl1()); plot(mdl1()$fcst); })
  output$plot2 <- renderPlot({ req(mdl2()); plot(mdl2()$fcst); })
  output$plot3 <- renderPlot({ req(mdl3()); plot(mdl3()$fcst); })
  output$plot4 <- renderPlot({ req(mdl4()); plot(mdl4()$fcst); })

}
```

Comment: I really appreciate that, I did same thing for peak type, and curve name  and used this code

 `mydata <- eventReactive(input$name, {
    req(input$name)
    data %>%
      filter(curve==input$name, delivery == input$reg, peak == input$Peak_type)
  })`  

for filtering all 3 categories which I have and now app is working. 

Thank you